# Handling passwords in R and Shiny app in .Renviron file as a secure production environment

Tags: r, postgresql, shiny, credentials, rpostgresql

Why is keeping your password, port, host, and all secrets of a database (e.g. PostgreSQL) in the .Renviron file safe for Shiny apps and R scripts?

I have a question about the .Renviron file and its security password. Although the .Renviron file is a hidden file in our file system, how does it guarantee the security of passwords (key, token) and information?

I hope to understand the security against malicious hacking of the .Renviron file to guard the passwords and secrets important of the PostgreSQL database connection. In addition to omitting the explicit password in the R script.

Comment: “Why is [keeping passwords in plain-text files] safe?” — It’s not. It may be OK depending on your setup but it is *not* perfectly safe, or ideal. Oh, and being “hidden” is not a security feature *at all*; it just helps to declutter file listings, nothing else (in fact, my Renviron file isn’t hidden at all). The safety (or lack thereof) of the file is dictated by its set of filesystem permissions and encryption (and the overall safety of your system). File visibility does not play a role.

Comment: [Here](https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/best-practices/managing-credentials/) you can find an overview regarding different options to protect your credentials in order of preference provided by posit.

Comment: @ismirsehregal It's worth noting that there are several caveats to that article. For one thing it's (obviously) RStudio centric, which is probably not what most people use for their production environment. More importantly, it does not mention file permissions at all, which is a rather glaring oversight.

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. @Konrad Rudolph What would be the safest procedure to keep your password, or any secret when building a shiny app and R programming language? 

ismirsegregal Thanks for the recommendation link. I was already aware of him. It is one of the first sites that is recommended on the subject in a quick google search, but it does not clarify all doubts. I believe that among all the recommendations on this site, Integrated security with DSN for Data Base (adbc::adbc()) may be the option that I'm looking for. But I'm not sure.

Comment: @CarlosZarzar Apart from the caveats I mentioned the Posit article basically summarises the established best practices: defer security to the account management (e.g. via DSN or whatever available mechanism) and if that is not feasible use the OS keychain. Apart from that, best practice is to limit permissions as much as feasible and to use fine-grained API tokens instead of passwords, where access can be revoked easily. For those I do use file-based solutions as well, and I rely on UNIX file permissions to keep them safe.